# C# My arrays are not populating answers. No matter what it always generates 0's

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the .txt file saved in the appropriate folder (to be honest, I have one saved in every single possible folder relating to this code) but no matter what it always populates a bunch of zeros.... Can someone show me where I went wrong?

```
    using System.IO;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System;
    
    namespace WindowsFormsAppSix6AttemptNumber6
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private double[] myArray =
            {
                1245.67,
                1189.55,
                1089.72,
                1456.88,
                2109.34,
                1987.55,
                1872.36
            };
            private void analyzeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string salesValue;
               Double[] sales = new double[8];
                int count = 0;
                double maxSales = Double.MinValue;
                double minSales =Double.MaxValue;
                double totalSales = 0;
    
                try
                {
                    StringReader dataStream = new StringReader("Sales.Txt");
    
                    salesValue = dataStream.ReadLine();
    
                    var total = sales.Sum();
                    var average = sales.Average();
                    var high = sales.Max();
                    var low = sales.Min();
    
                    while (salesValue != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            sales[count] = Convert.ToDouble(salesValue);
    
                            totalSales += sales[count];
    
                            if (sales[count] > maxSales)
                                maxSales = sales[count];
    
                            if (sales[count] < minSales)
                                minSales = sales[count];
    
                            count++;
                        }
                        catch (FormatException)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\tException: '" + salesValue + "'");
    
                            salesValue = dataStream.ReadLine();
                        }
    
                        dataStream.Close();
    
    
    
                        for (int item = 0; item < 7; item++)
                            listBoxLbl.Items.Add(sales[item]);
    
                        string listItems = string.Join(",\n", sales);
    
    
                        Console.WriteLine(listItems);
                        Console.WriteLine(totalSales);
                        Console.WriteLine(maxSales);
                        Console.WriteLine(minSales);
    
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
    
            private void exitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

below is what it does when i use the analyze button. I have been going in circles with this one and cant figure out what I am doing wrong....
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFGgv.png

Comment: Are you sure you wanted `new StringReader("Sales.Txt")` and not a `StreamReader`? Did you do any [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? [Use a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)
Step through your code and observe what each line of code does. 
Identify where your program differs from your expectations by comparing these intermediate results with expected results. Work backwards from there to narrow down the cause of the problem. 
Then ask a _specific_ question if you are still confused by your code's behavior.

Comment: You might find those links helpful if you actually bothered to read and try to understand the links instead of lashing out at me for not doing _your_ job for you. You expect non-zero values in your listbox, but you only get zeros, so look at the line that adds those values from the array. Does it seem to be working correctly? Take a look at the line where you populate the array from each line in the file. Does _that_ seem to be working correctly? If so check if the lines you parse into doubles are actually the lines in the file. Debugging is an essential skill for a programmer to have.

Comment: In fact the comments posted are *not* useless or irrelevant (nor even snarky).  They are 100% dead on.  If you want to read from a file you need a `streamreader` not a `stringreader`.  Then step debugging would allow you to see one one at a time what data is coming into the app (if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's your intention, you should use "StreamReader".

```
//StringReader dataStream = new StringReader("Sales.Txt");
StreamReader dataStream = new StreamReader("Sales.Txt");
```

"sales[count] = Convert.ToDouble(salesValue);"
"salesValue = dataStream.ReadLine();"
"Console.WriteLine(ex);"
Please Put a breakpoint here and test it.

'salesValue' is file name.
[breakpoint 'salesValue'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikZk2.png)

Comment: thank you for your help, I guess VS likes to autofill my typing and I dont catch it sometimes.